# In pig How to concatenate all items in bag ?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a structure like

```
 {A, {1,2,3}}
 {B, {4,5,6}}
```

What I want is

```
 {A, "1|2|3"}
 {B, "4|5|6"}
```

- I looked at CONCAT operator but that will not help me achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most easily achieved with a Python UDF.

**myudfs.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('concated: string')
def concat_bag(BAG):
    return '|'.join([ str(i) for i in BAG ])
```

It can be used like:

```
Register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;

-- Schema of A is: A:{ T:(letter: chararray, B_of_nums: {num: int}) }

B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOTUPLE(T.letter, myfuncs.concat_bag(T.B_of_nums)) ;

-- The output should be:
-- (A, 1|2|3)
-- (B, 1|2|3)
```

Comment: Wow,cool.  Python UDF seem a lot easier than Java ones !

Just wondering if someone did perf analysis on these ?

Comment: @Ajeet It all compiles down to Java byte code, so Java and Python UDFs should have very similar speeds.

Comment: `@outputSchema('concated: string')` should be `@outputSchema('concated: chararray')`