# How to get this output from pig Latin in MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to get the following output from Pig Latin / Hadoop

```
((39,50,60,42,15,Bachelor,Male),5)
((40,35,HS-grad,Male),2)
((39,45,15,30,12,7,HS-grad,Female),6)
```

from the following data sample
[data sample for adult data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpmQ5.png)

I have written the following Pig Latin script:

```
sensitive = LOAD '/mdsba/sample2.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (AGE,EDU,SEX,SALARY);
BV= group  sensitive by (EDU,SEX) ; 
BVA= foreach BV generate group as EDU, COUNT (sensitive) as dd:long;
Dump BVA ;
```

Unfortunately, the results come out like this

```
((Bachelor,Male),5)
((HS-grad,Male),2)
```

Comment: Have look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104792/in-pig-how-to-concatenate-all-items-in-bag

Answer (score 1):

Than try to project the AGE data too. 
Something like this:

```
BVA= foreach BV generate 
    sensitive.AGE as AGE,
    FLATTEN(group) as (EDU,SEX), 
    COUNT(sensitive) as dd:long;
```

Another suggestion is to specify the datatype when you load the data.

```
sensitive = LOAD '/mdsba/sample2.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (AGE:int,EDU:chararray,SEX:chararray,SALARY:chararray);
```

Comment: Thanks Kecso, but your code generates error message as follows "Projected field [AGE] does not exist in schema: group:tuple(EDU:bytearray,SEX:bytearray),sensitive:bag{:tuple(AGE:bytearray,EDU:bytearray,SEX:bytearray,SALARY:bytearray)}."

Comment: Yes you have to access it from the sensitive bag: sensitive.AGE